# JSON, unable to use key to display the required info!

Tags: android, json

im using android 1.5 and currently working on JSON related stuff. i have this info in a String variable **str**

```
{
"UserInfo":
    [
    {"LastName":"b","FirstName":"a","Gender":"Male","User: ":1},
    {"LastName":"b","FirstName":"a","Gender":"Male","User: ":2},
    {"LastName":"b","FirstName":"a","Gender":"Male","User: ":3}
    ]
}
{
"Info":
    [
    {"LastName":"d","FirstName":"c","Gender":"Male","User: ":5},
    {"LastName":"d","FirstName":"c","Gender":"Male","User: ":6},
    {"LastName":"d","FirstName":"c","Gender":"Male","User: ":7},
    {"LastName":"d","FirstName":"c","Gender":"Male","User: ":8},
    {"LastName":"d","FirstName":"c","Gender":"Male","User: ":9},
    ]
}
```

i have all this info in **str**, now by using key (i.e. UserInfo and Info) i wana use info to display all its elements. how can i do that??
thanks!

Comment: to check your json format you can add the string in http://json.parser.online.fr/ to verify.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, but still it worked for me
what i do is i put these JSON objects in JSONArray and pass that Array to a PHP function in which i used loops to get the required key and its value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's information about how to handle JSON:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
Some code examples here: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/